# Firebase pubsub/function running mutiple times

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have 2 firebase/gcp cloud function, one of them is a pubsub described like this

pubsub one

```js
exports.bgTask = functionsV2.pubsub.onMessagePublished(
    {topic:"bg-task", retry: false, },
  async (event) => {
 try{
  const response = await axios.get(`URL_OF_THE_OTHER_FUNCTION`, {
          params: {
            data,
            session,
          },
   });
  return null
}
catch(err){
        functionsV2.logger.error("Error calling API");
}

})
```

another one

```js
exports.webServer = functionsV2.https.onRequest(
  { cors: true,  },
  (req, res) => {
   functionsV2.logger.log('Rec Request', mainPath)
  // task // mostly business logics // db operations
})
```

and triggering the pub sub like this

```js
   const pubSubClient = new PubSub({
          credentials: ***,
          projectId: ***,
        });

   const messageId = await pubSubClient
      .topic(topicName)
      .publishMessage({ data: bufferData });
```

I am calling the `webServer` from the `bgTask` via pubsub client, but it seems like `webServer` is running more than once (up to 8 times), I do have same errors but I'm handling them and ignoring them as they are not blockers.

I have tested the task in another function locally and also in vercel, worked smooth and fine with no retry but I am not sure why GCP is making it run that often. I read something about `at least once delivery` but this seems to be overhead/hassle.

> ONE IMPORTANT THING: I TRIED TO PUT A LOGIC TO CHECK IF THE FUNCTION IS ALREADY RUNNING, BUT THE MAIN ISSUE HERE IS, THEY ARE BEING TRIGGERED EVEN BEFORE THE LAST ONE IS DONE

#### Logs

from pubsub
[image]

from web server
[image]

is there any solution out there to run the function only once, i don't need retries on failure?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full code that doesn't work the way you expect.  You've completely removed all the implementation details, so we can't possibly tell what you are doing or how it's supposed to work.  Please read about how to create a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit the question to show the code, logs, and procedure that anyone can use to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Sorry about that. i added bit more code to the pubsub one but the webServer function is mostly consist of business login task/db operations. i'm not sure how can i add more context to the issue. Please let me know if i can put more info to give the question more clarity.
in short, i wanted to ask if there's any way to stop auto retrying of gcp functions. You can see i already put retry: false in the code but that's not working properly

Comment: Please add function logs and the procedure you use the trigger the behavior.  We should be able to duplicate your observations using the instructions you provide.

Comment: Ok, i added logs from the two, you can see i put a log in the webServer function when it's get called. i has been repeated many times, but i am not sure why in the pubsub function's logs i have only 1 response with error. but i checked carefully and found every time the task/operations in the webServer got succeeded.